How to numerically solve a second order derivative equation with multiple boundary conditions using python
As suggested by title, right now I am trying to numerically solve a second order derivative equation using python. The python package in use is Scipy and specifically solve_bvp. The equation I am working with is
d2y/dx2-ay-by3=0, where a < 0 and b > 0.
With four boundary conditions: y(±∞) = ±1 and dy/dx = 0 at x=±∞, and according to this paper, an exact solution of the equation in a form of y ∝ tanh(x) can be obtained. So what I want to do is to get a similar numerical result to this exact solution.
The code I wrote and modified by chatgpt is provided below. Using solve_bvp, I was able to include two of the four boundary conditions which are y(±∞) = ±1. However, the numerical result I got isn't like a tanh function at all but like a cosine function, which I suspect that this is because I could only provide 2 boundary conditions when using solve_bvp.  When I tried to include four boundary conditions, the system always sends out an error message saying
ValueError: `bc` return is expected to have shape (2,), but actually has (4,).

I was wondering whether there is a way that I can add the extra two boundary conditions to the solve_bvp or there are other solver which can support multiple boundary conditions.
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import solve_bvp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a = -1
b = 1
p0 = 1

# Define the differential equation
def y_derivative(x, y):
    return np.vstack((y[1], a * y[0] + b * (y[0]**3)))

# Define the boundary conditions
def bc(ya, yb):
    return np.array([ya[0] + p0, yb[0] - p0])

# Generate a set of points
x = np.linspace(-100, 100, 100)

# Solve the boundary value problem
y0 = np.zeros((2, x.size))
sol = solve_bvp(y_derivative, bc, x, y0)

# Calculate the exact solution
y_exact = np.tanh(x)

# Plot the numerical solution
plt.plot(x, sol.sol(x)[0], label='Numerical Solution')

# Plot the exact solution
plt.plot(x, y_exact, label='Exact Solution', linestyle='--')

# Customize plot
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.title('Comparison of Numerical and Exact Solutions')
plt.legend()
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()


Have you checked (by differentiating twice) that y=tanh(x) actually satisfies your equation with a=-1 and b=1? I'm not convinced that it does. You might also like to start with an initial condition that actually satisfied the boundary conditions (which can be brought a lot closer than x=-100 or +100).

How can one impose 4 boundary conditions on a second-order ODE? Are a and b unknowns?

I've discussed the construction of more topical boundary conditions in https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3164652/115115. You are forcing here the impossible, which leads to a break of the solution iteration due to non-convergence. Starting and ending the solution on the stable manifold of the saddle points will greatly regularize the solution process.

Lets build upon your MCVE:
import numpy as np
from scipy import integrate, optimize
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

Notice we add the parameters p:
def model(x, y, p):
    return np.array([
        y[1],
        p[0] * y[0] + p[1] * y[0] ** 3
    ])

We add two BC and we also need to add parameter p:
def bc(ya, yb, p):
    return np.array([
        ya[0] + 1.,
        yb[0] - 1.,
        ya[1],
        yb[1],
    ])

We restrict a bit the domain:
x = np.linspace(-5., 5., 500)

And prepare the grid to be closer to it's real situation:
y0 = np.zeros((2, x.size))
y0[0, :200] = -1.
y0[0, -200:] = +1.

Now integration performs well:
sol = integrate.solve_bvp(model, bc, x, y0, p=(-1., 1.), max_nodes=5000)

#       message: The algorithm converged to the desired accuracy.
#       success: True
#        status: 0
#             x: [-5.000e+00 -4.980e+00 ...  4.980e+00  5.000e+00]
#           sol: <scipy.interpolate._interpolate.PPoly object at 0x7f66e55ff740>
#             p: [-8.642e+00  8.642e+00]
#             y: [[-1.000e+00 -1.000e+00 ...  1.000e+00  1.000e+00]
#                 [ 0.000e+00  1.299e-09 ...  1.299e-09  0.000e+00]]
#            yp: [[ 0.000e+00  1.299e-09 ...  1.299e-09  0.000e+00]
#                 [ 6.476e-08  6.499e-08 ... -6.499e-08 -6.476e-08]]
# rms_residuals: [ 5.282e-14  5.863e-14 ...  5.978e-14  5.293e-14]
#         niter: 2

It renders as follow:

Which fits definitely the profile of a hyperbolic tangent:
def fit(x, a):
    return np.tanh(a * x)

popt, pcov = optimize.curve_fit(fit, sol.x, sol.y[0])
# (array([2.07873794]), array([[1.88993946e-12]]))



This is a great solution. But I'm still left wondering. If you try y=tanh(Cx) then d^2y/dx^2=-2C^2(y-y^3). So a=-2C^2 and b=-a. ONE of these solutions is C=2.07873794 and a=-b=8.641987, as your code produces. Do you know why it is producing this particular one, though, as any value of C should be able to give a solution?

If you include the actual Jacobian in the solve_bvp call (see https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.solve_bvp.html) then the solver may do a better job.
As with @jlandercy's solution I had to increase the number of nodes. Turning verbose=2 on shows that, otherwise, the solver gives up and returns a non-converged solution.
Note that the exact solution with a=-1, b=1 is y=tanh(x/sqrt(2)), not y=tanh(x). However, it's a non-linear equation, so it's just plausible that there may be more than 1 solution.
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import solve_bvp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a = -1
b = 1
p0 = 1

# Define the differential equation
def y_derivative(x, y):
    return np.vstack( ( y[1], a * y[0] + b * y[0] ** 3 ) )

def fun_jac(x, y):
    J = np.zeros( ( 2, 2, x.size ) )
    J[0,1,:] = 1.0
    J[1,0,:] = a + 3 * b * y[0] ** 2
    return J

# Define the boundary conditions
def bc(ya, yb):
    return np.array([ya[0] + p0, yb[0] - p0])

# Generate a set of points
x = np.linspace(-10, 10, 100 )

# Solve the boundary value problem
y0 = np.zeros( ( 2, x.size ) )
y0[0] = 2 * x / ( x[-1] - x[0] )
y0[1] = 2.0 / ( x[-1] - x[0] )
sol = solve_bvp(y_derivative, bc, x, y0, tol=1.0e-10, fun_jac=fun_jac, max_nodes=100000, verbose=2 )

# Calculate the exact solution
y_exact = np.tanh(x/np.sqrt( 2.0 ) )

# Plot the numerical solution
plt.plot(x, sol.sol(x)[0], label='Numerical Solution')

# Plot the exact solution
plt.plot(x, y_exact, label='Exact Solution', linestyle='--')

# Customize plot
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.title('Comparison of Numerical and Exact Solutions')
plt.legend()
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()

Output:


Hi thanks for the awesome reply. I was wondering whether you can provide any intuition about how you set up the fun_jac here. I've been digging around the scipy documentation but no luck thus far.

Well, your derivative function is just [f0,f1]=[y1,a.y0+by0^3] so the coded Jacobian is just the set of partial derivatives [[df0/dy0,df0/dy1],[df1/dy0,df1/dy1]]. However, I had a another look at your problem and it seems the Jacobian is less important than simply increasing the number of allowed nodes. If you put verbose=2 then the solver tells you when it has packed up due to insufficient nodes. Unfortunately, it still fails if you move the boundaries too far away.

BTW, you don't need to try specifying that the derivative goes to 0 at infinity. If the function was tending to a fixed value at "infinity" then (nearly all) such functions would have a derivative tending to 0 there. Those that don't are fairly pathological.
